# Limit ScaleTransform to a maximum height and width

Tags: c#, wpf, image, scaletransform

Is there a way to limit `ScaleTransform` to a maximum height and width?

I have a `Viewbox` with a background `Image` set to stretch to "None".  In this `Viewbox` I also have a `ItemsControl` presenting smaller images on a `Canvas`.  Since the background image can be chosen by operator, the image can vary in pixel size, and the operator therefore need to be able to scale the smaller images accordingly.

But if the scaling factor is either set very large on a medium sized background image, or the background image has a small size, the `ItemsControl` images end up overflowing the container and blocking other functionality.

So how can I set a limit to the `ScaleTransform`?

XAML:

```
<Viewbox Grid.Column="1">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="{Binding Path=BackgroundImage}" Stretch="None" />
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ThrusterCollection}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Bottom" Value="{Binding Path=CanvasYPosition}" />
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=CanvasXPosition}" />
                    <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding Path=ParentRovIllustration.ThrusterImageScale}" 
                                            ScaleY="{Binding Path=ParentRovIllustration.ThrusterImageScale}" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Image Source="{Binding Path=ThrusterImage}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: The ScaleTransform doesn't know anything about the element or property it is applied to, and can therefore not by itself limit a width or height. Implement an appropriate limit on your ThrusterImageScale property.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Clemens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1136211/clemens)' comment, doing the limitation in code worked fine.  I just calculated a maximum scaling value for the slider, based on the smaller images (thrusters) at maximum being scaled to half the background image width.  This ended up being my solution.

C#:

```
private string _backgroundImageFilePath;
public string BackgroundImageFilePath {
    get { return _backgroundImageFilePath; }
    set {
        SetNotify(ref _backgroundImageFilePath, value);
        try {
            BackgroundImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(BackgroundImageFilePath));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException) {
            BackgroundImage = ImageNotFoundBitmapImage;
        }
        catch (Exception) {
            BackgroundImage = ImageInvalidBitmapImage;
        }
        ThrusterImageMaximumScale = BackgroundImage.Width / (2 * RovIllustrationThruster.VerticalThrusterBitmapImage.Width);
        ThrusterImageMaximumScale = Math.Round(ThrusterImageMaximumScale, 1);
        if (ThrusterImageScale > ThrusterImageMaximumScale) {
            ThrusterImageScale = ThrusterImageMaximumScale;
        }
        ConfigurationHandler.IsDirty = true;
    }
}
```